# Pivot data issue how can group this data in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have been looking at the `Pivot` function in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I would like to achieve the following results

```
    OrderName   Processed   NotProcessed    OrderDescription
    Pasta       1           1               Pasta Order
    Fruit       2           1               Fruit Order
    Meat        2           1               Meat Order
```

I have tried to use a pivot but my column `OrderName` is a `varchar` .

This is the table and data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[OrderSummary]','U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[OrderSummary]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderSummary]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderNo] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [OrderStatus] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OrderName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [OrderDescription] [varchar](350) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderSummary] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[OrderSummary] ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderSummary]([Id], [OrderNo], [OrderStatus], [Category], [OrderName], [OrderDescription])
      SELECT 
         1, N'100', N'Processed', N'Pasta', N'PastaOrder', N'Pasta Order' 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
         2, N'101', N'Processed', N'Fruit', N'FruitOrder', N'Fruit Order' 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
         3, N'102', N'NotProcessed', N'Meat', N'MeatOrder', N'Meat Order' 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
         5, N'103', N'NotProcessed', N'Pasta', N'PastaOrder', N'Pasta Order' 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
         6, N'104', N'Processed', N'Fruit', N'FruitOrder', N'Fruit Order' 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
         8, N'105', N'NotProcessed', N'Meat', N'MeatOrder', N'Meat Order' 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
         9, N'106', N'Processed', N'Meat', N'MeatOrder', N'Meat Order' 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
         10, N'107', N'NotProcessed', N'Fruit', N'FruitOrder', N'Fruit Order'

COMMIT;
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[OrderSummary] OFF;
```

Any suggestions?

Will create a sql fiddle if it makes easier.

Comment: To achieve the suggested result there is not need for pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query gives the required result:

```
SELECT OrderName
,SUM(CASE WHEN OrderStatus = 'Processed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Processed
,SUM(CASE WHEN OrderStatus = 'NotProcessed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotProcessed
,OrderDescription
FROM OrderSummary
GROUP BY OrderName, OrderDescription
```